Hiding Tkinter window during the setup works inconsistently
I want to hide a Tkinter window before the setup (where the window is centered) is complete, to avoid a window breifly popping up in the corner of the screen. In this answer, I found that you can use root.attributes('-alpha', 0.0) to make the window transparent during the setup, and then use root.attributes('-alpha', 1.0) to make it opaque again. However, it doesn't always work. It works most of the time, but sometimes, often when the computer is currently using a large amount of RAM, the window still briefly pops up in the corner.
To check where it fails, I had set the first root.attributes() call to '-alpha', 0.5 and removed the second call. The result is that it sets itself transparent only after popping up in the corner and centering the window, not before.
I tried to use root.withdraw() and root.deiconify() instead of root.attributes() calls, but it yielded the same results.
Here's the code. But keep in mind that I failed to reproduce the problem using this minimal example. It only worked with the rest of my code.
import tkinter as tk

def center_window(root, root_width, root_height):
    # Makes the window transparent, hiding it
    root.attributes('-alpha', 0.0)

    # Centering the window
    top_left_corner_x = 0
    top_left_corner_y = 0    
    root.geometry(f'{root_width}x{root_height}+{top_left_corner_x}+{top_left_corner_y}')
    
    screen_width = root.winfo_screenwidth()
    screen_height = root.winfo_screenheight()
    offset_x = int((screen_width - root_width) / 2)
    offset_y = int((screen_height - root_height) / 2)
    root.geometry(f'{root_width}x{root_height}+{offset_x}+{offset_y}')
    
    # Makes the window opaque again
    root.attributes('-alpha', 1.0)

root = tk.Tk()
root_width = 640
root_height = 480
root.geometry(f'{root_width}x{root_height}')

center_window(root, root_width, root_height)
root.mainloop()


Try reming all of the root.geometrys apart from the last one in center_window. If you have only 1 root.geometry call before root.mainloop it might do the trick. Also what OS/python versions are you using?

@TheLizzard I'm using Windows 10 (64-bit) and Python 3.13.0. The first root.geometry() call is actually needed to make the window appear on the main monitor for dual-monitor users. But I tried deleting all root.geometry() except the one in the center_window(), and it still didn't work.

Like you say, your example fails to show the problem. You might try using root.withdraw() immediately after root = tk.Tk()

@Derek That's exactly what worked. Thank you!
